# Windows layout : see the navigator

Tags: netbeans

In netbeans I should want a layout like the second in this page : http://wiki.netbeans.org/WinsysLayoutFor65

The navigator is in bottom, left side. I can't do that. If I select menu Window/Navigating/Navigator, the navigators appears in the middle panel. If I drag drop it, it goes in left, or in bottom, but never in bottom left.

How is it possible to put it in bottom left ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

go to the "window" tab, and click on "reset windows".  [link](http:///http://forums.netbeans.org/topic8372.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to drag it directly into the bottom of (not under!) the files/project window.

As an alternative open the inspector: Navigation->Inspector

(which should appear out of the box in the bottom left)

and after this add the navigator to it via drag and drop.

Comment: If I drag/drop in the bottom or under or in the corner, nothing append. 

If I do Navigation->Inspector, it appears in the middle panel, with the editors.

Comment: strange. which OS are you using?

Comment: try to move the .netbeans folder to .netbeansOld then restart nb and see if the inspector then shows up under the project window. if not I fear you have to look into the bug database + post it there. another option is to try the latest 6.9beta and see if then the drag-and-drop-window support is better

Comment: My OS is Mandriva 2010.

If I move .netbeans and relaunch netbeans, I'm please to see again the navigator at a good place ! (for me).

Planty thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to move the entire popup window, but only the tab inside the window named "Navigator".

This is different to `eclipse` and thus probably confusing to most of us.

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible to put it in bottom left ?

I've managed to put the navigator in bottom left by doing the following:

1 Click Navigator => Inspect => Members

2 The Navigator window appears

3 Click the little circle at the top right to dock the Navigator

The Navigator will appears in the bottom left.